# PHP- Array with same value with different key - Make on

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

What it would happen if i have same value on different key in php? So I need to remove other keys with value and keep only one.Either array could be single or multidimentional.
Tak a look at the code please

---

```
Array
(
      [success] => Array
         (
            [0] => Done.
            [1] => Done.
         )

      [error] => Array
         (
            [0] => This request has already been processed.
            [1] => This request has already been processed.
            [2] => This request has already been processed.
            [3] => You Don't Have Permission.
            [4] => You Don't Have Permission.
         )

      [warning] => Array
         (
         )

)
```

As you can see on `[error]` and `[success]` array there is 2/3 same value on different key.
Now What can i do? to keep only one.
Like the below one

---

```
Array
(
      [success] => Array
         (
            [0] => Done.
         )

      [error] => Array
         (
            [0] => This request has already been processed.
            [1] => You Don't Have Permission.
         )

      [warning] => Array
         (
         )

)
```

Answer (score 5):

For your example data you might use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
$result = array_map("array_unique", $arrays);
```